# Jest spyOn not works

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, mocking

So I have a file that consists of a couple of functions. And I wrote a test for `getOpeningHours`.

- The `getOpeningHours` use `isLocationOrderAheadAvailable` function
- The `isLocationOrderAheadAvailable` function is not using `getOpeningHours` so it's not a circular dep issue
- Both `getOpeningHours` and `isLocationOrderAheadAvailable` are exported functions
- Both functions came from same file.

```js
import * as locationUtils from './location';
import {
    isLocationOrderAheadAvailable,
    getProductItemsFromMenu,
    resolveOpeningHours,
    getOpenedTimeRanges,
    getOpeningHours,
} from './location';


describe('getOpeningHours', () => {
        it('should return same locationHours if isLocationOrderAheadAvailable is false', () => {
            jest.spyOn(locationUtils, 'isLocationOrderAheadAvailable').mockImplementation(
                jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false)
            );

            const openingHours = getOpeningHours(validLocationEntry);
            expect(openingHours).toEqual(locationHours);
        });
});
```

So eventually the `isLocationOrderAheadAvailable` not been mocked at all. The wired thing is that I did exactly the same in a different test and it worked.

Sorry, I can't give a working example of this.

Comment: It might happen because you're mocking the function which you import in the same file.

Comment: I think `mockImplementation` is just supposed to return a straight value, not a mocked return value, no?

Comment: `*` import is read-only by design, you shouldn't try to modify it as may not work. And you cannot mock a function that is used in the same module it's defined, unless it's used as a method everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Changing from `export function isLocationOrderAheadAvailable(...)` to `export const isLocationOrderAheadAvailable = (...): =>` makes jest.spyOn work.

But I still don't understand why. I think it might be connected with JS hoisting but I don't know how jest interacts with it.

Comment: maybe related to `babel-jest` (transpilation before test)